# Parquet String to timestamp conversion in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

I have parquet files generated by some code. I created a DDL for that data, added table in hive and pointed to those parquet files in hdfs. When I try to query the table, all fields look perfect. But, for timestamp fields, hive is giving an exception.

```
HiveException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.TimestampWritable
```

Actually, timestamp fields are stored as strings in parquet, but my hive table fields are of type timestamp. I think this causes the issue, but what is right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open bug in Hive.

And documented at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15079

Comment: Check my answer and accept it if you find it helpful

Answer (score 4):

I figured out an alternative to my own problem. I changed the column type of `TIMESTAMP` column to `STRING` and while fetching data I used `from_unixtime` method to cast that particular column to the intended date format and was able to fetch it.
But, the problem over here was if my date value is `2020-02-27 15:40:22` and when I fetched the data of this column via Hive it was returning `EpochSeconds` i.e `15340232000000`.
So, I solved this problem in Hive via below query:

```
select *, from_unixtime(cast(SOURCE_LOAD_DATE as BIGINT) DIV 1000000) as SOURCE_LOAD_DATE from table_name;
```

Using the above query I was able to get the proper date with timestamp value.

***Note***: You will need to cast every column which has timestamp data.

This is the only trick which I could think of. I hope this might help you or others!

Comment: If you want to read my problem then here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60492836/timestamp-not-behaving-as-intended-with-parquet-in-hive