# Spark, Parquet: filter DataFrame after Timestamp Column throws error

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have an issue with Spark 2.4 and Parquet Files. 
I read parquet files from a storage location with pyspark and then store them in a Spark DataFrame. In the definition of the Dataframe I can see that the TIMESTAMP column is of type bigint. But the printSchema function returns long for this column. That is the first thing I find confusing.

```
>>> df = spark.read.parquet(store_path)
>>> df
DataFrame[NAME: string, CITY: string, TIMESTAMP: bigint]
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CITY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TIMESTAMP: long (nullable = true)
```

The goal is to filter after the TIMESTAMP Column, which is currently a  unix timestamp in nanoseconds. Therefore I have a start_date and end_date.

```
>>> df = df.filter(col('TIMESTAMP').between(start_date, end_date))
```

If I filter and there is a record in between start_date and end_date, then everything works. But if there is no record in this timeframe, instead of returning an empty Dataframe, the following error is thrown.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FilterPredicate column: insert_timestamp's declared type (java.lang.Long) does not match the schema found in file metadata. Column insert_timestamp is of type: INT96
Valid types for this column are: [class org.apache.parquet.io.api.Binary]
```

As a result, I add a new column with the content of the TIMESTAMP column casted to timestamp. Then I remove the TIMESTAMP Column.

```
>>> df = df.withColumn('tmp', from_unixtime(col("TIMESTAMP")/1000000000).cast("timestamp"))
>>> df = df.drop("TIMESTAMP")
```

But the filter is still not working, I get the same error altrough there is no column TIMESTAMP anymore in the DataFrame. 
Has anyone an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Instead of casting it as a `Timestamp` try `BIGINT` again.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The error remains the same.

Comment: Try casting it in BIGINT first and then divide by 1000000

Comment: did this: `df = df.withColumn('tmp', (col("TIMESTAMP")/1000000).cast("bigint"))`, but still the same error.  When I use a udf function, pass there the TIMESTAMP column and then return something complete different I still get the same error. It has to do something with the parquet file metadata or something like that...

Comment: Try to convert the timestamp to epoch seconds and then try to convert it using spark.sql.

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/60492836/7760910

Comment: Thanks again! I did this: `df1 = spark.sql("Select *, from_unixtime(cast(TIMESTAMP as BIGINT) DIV 1000000000) as tmp FROM df")`, but filtering still doesn't work. get the same error, althrough I removed the column TIMESTAMP afterwards...

Comment: Can you try registering temp table and then execute a HQL query like the one I did? Spark supports HQL so, shouldn't be a issue. Just check whether it works. If it doesn't work just post the query you tried

Comment: solved it! Thanks!

Comment: How did you do it ?

Comment: Can you post your solution so that it can help others.